# Problems with "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying initialize my local rails server but I haven't been able to, 
because when I write "rails server", show me this message:

```
=> Booting WEBrick 
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
=> Call with -d to detach 
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
Exiting 
/home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in 
`require': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError) 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in 
`require' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in 
`load_dependency' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in 
`new_constants_in' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in 
`load_dependency' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in 
`require' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/config.ru:6 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ 
rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/config.ru:1:in `new' 
from /home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/config.ru:1
```

Regards, Iván

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in "/home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/mysql2/ruby/1.8/gems/ activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb" line 239.  It's calling:

```
require 'one/thing', 'another/thing'
```

It's possible that something in your config is causing it to do this.

[Off-topic]
English help :)

1. "I haven't can" => "I haven't been able to"
2. "Rewards, Iván" => "Regards, Iván"

Hopefully you don't mind.
[/Off-topic]

EDIT | I'd probably check this line first: "/home/distriker/Documentos/public_html/auth/config.ru:6"

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found my error. The error was that in config.ru the line that call "rake" have two params. That was because I am trying different things in the past >__<. Well, also thanks for your english correction, I will try remember your advices. I'm spanish, sincerely, very thanks.

Comment: :)  Glad you got it working.  Estoy seguro de que tu inglés es mucho mejor que mi castellano!